# Cylindrical coordinates plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-3dplot, tikz-3d

I wonder how can I plot this 3D object by using only `tikz-3dplot`:

[image]

Comment: It would be great if you could  show us what you have tried. Posting a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that indicates what you are trying to do makes it easier for people to understand what you want. It also makes it easier for people to help you, since they have some code to start from, and hence much more likely that some one will try to help you.

Comment: What I have tried is plot r=\sqrt{cos 2\varphi} on (Oxy) plane, but it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome! Thanks for your clarifications! The following allows you to specify `a`, `b` and the height `h` of the object. This is achieved by defining functions and plotting them in a parametric plot. The angle of visibility, i.e. the point at which the solid line turns dashed, is computed numerically.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{40}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords,line join=round,line cap=round,
    >=stealth,declare function={R(\t)=sqrt(abs(cos(2*(\t))));
    a=3;b=2;h=3;}]
 \draw[->] (-4,0,0) -- (4,0,0) node[pos=1.05]{$x$};
 \draw[->] (0,-4,0) -- (0,4,0) node[pos=1.05]{$y$};
 \draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,4) node[pos=1.05]{$z$};
 \edef\myt{-45} 
 \edef\mytcrit{-45}
 \edef\myxmax{0pt}
 \loop
 \path[overlay] ({a*R(\myt)*cos(\myt)},{b*R(\myt)*sin(\myt)},0) coordinate(aux);    
 \pgfpointanchor{aux}{center}%
 \pgfgetlastxy{\myx}{\myy}%
 \ifdim\myx>\myxmax
  \edef\mytcrit{\myt}%
  \edef\myxmax{\myx}%
 \fi
 \ifnum\myt<45
 \edef\myt{\the\numexpr\myt+1}
 \repeat    
 \draw[densely dashed] plot[variable=\t,domain=\mytcrit:45,smooth]
    ({a*R(\t)*cos(\t)},{b*R(\t)*sin(\t)},0);
 \draw[densely dashed] plot[variable=\t,domain=-45:\mytcrit,smooth]
    ({-a*R(\t)*cos(\t)},{-b*R(\t)*sin(\t)},0);
 \draw plot[variable=\t,domain=-45:\mytcrit,smooth]
    ({a*R(\t)*cos(\t)},{b*R(\t)*sin(\t)},0);
 \draw plot[variable=\t,domain=\mytcrit:45,smooth]
    ({-a*R(\t)*cos(\t)},{-b*R(\t)*sin(\t)},0);
 \draw ({a*R(\mytcrit)*cos(\mytcrit)},{b*R(\mytcrit)*sin(\mytcrit)},0)
 -- ({a*R(\mytcrit)*cos(\mytcrit)},{b*R(\mytcrit)*sin(\mytcrit)},h)
 ({-a*R(\mytcrit)*cos(\mytcrit)},{-b*R(\mytcrit)*sin(\mytcrit)},0)
 -- ({-a*R(\mytcrit)*cos(\mytcrit)},{-b*R(\mytcrit)*sin(\mytcrit)},h);
 \draw plot[variable=\t,domain=-45:45,smooth]
    ({a*R(\t)*cos(\t)},{b*R(\t)*sin(\t)},h);
 \draw plot[variable=\t,domain=-45:45,smooth]
    ({-a*R(\t)*cos(\t)},{b*R(\t)*sin(\t)},h);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or with a solid appearance.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{40}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords,line join=round,line cap=round,
    >=stealth,declare function={R(\t)=sqrt(abs(cos(2*(\t))));
    a=3;b=2;h=3;}]
 \draw[->] (-4,0,0) -- (4,0,0) node[pos=1.05]{$x$};
 \draw[->] (0,-4,0) -- (0,4,0) node[pos=1.05]{$y$};
 \draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,4) node[pos=1.05]{$z$};
 \edef\myt{-45} 
 \edef\mytcrit{-45}
 \edef\myxmax{0pt}
 \loop
 \path[overlay] ({a*R(\myt)*cos(\myt)},{b*R(\myt)*sin(\myt)},0) coordinate(aux);    
 \pgfpointanchor{aux}{center}%
 \pgfgetlastxy{\myx}{\myy}%
 \ifdim\myx>\myxmax
  \edef\mytcrit{\myt}%
  \edef\myxmax{\myx}%
 \fi
 \ifnum\myt<45
 \edef\myt{\the\numexpr\myt+1}
 \repeat    
 \draw[densely dashed] plot[variable=\t,domain=\mytcrit:45,smooth]
    ({a*R(\t)*cos(\t)},{b*R(\t)*sin(\t)},0);
 \draw[densely dashed] plot[variable=\t,domain=-45:\mytcrit,smooth]
    ({-a*R(\t)*cos(\t)},{-b*R(\t)*sin(\t)},0);
 \draw[left color=gray,right color=gray!80,middle color=gray!20,fill opacity=0.6] 
  plot[variable=\t,domain=-45:\mytcrit,smooth]
    ({a*R(\t)*cos(\t)},{b*R(\t)*sin(\t)},0)
    -- plot[variable=\t,domain=\mytcrit:-45,smooth]
    ({a*R(\t)*cos(\t)},{b*R(\t)*sin(\t)},h) --cycle;
 \draw[left color=gray!70!black,right color=gray!80,middle color=gray!50,fill opacity=0.6] plot[variable=\t,domain=\mytcrit:45,smooth]
    ({-a*R(\t)*cos(\t)},{-b*R(\t)*sin(\t)},0)
    -- plot[variable=\t,domain=45:\mytcrit,smooth]
    ({-a*R(\t)*cos(\t)},{-b*R(\t)*sin(\t)},h) -- cycle;
 \draw[fill=gray,fill opacity=0.6] plot[variable=\t,domain=-45:45,smooth]
    ({a*R(\t)*cos(\t)},{b*R(\t)*sin(\t)},h);
 \draw[fill=gray,fill opacity=0.6] plot[variable=\t,domain=-45:45,smooth]
    ({-a*R(\t)*cos(\t)},{b*R(\t)*sin(\t)},h);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi!!

I already have my hand written note on how I got the form of the object, but since I can't upload it to here for you so I would rather tell you what I did.
You can let x=ar.cos\varphi, y=br.sin\varphi (r is radius in polar coordinates). From the first equation you can have r^4 = r^2 cos(2\varphi), hence r = \sqrt{cos(2\varphi)} > 0, you can sketch this graph on 2D plane easily

Comment: @LêNguyênBách The first equation is cut off at its right so I do not know what it is. Does the right bracket have an exponent, and if so, is it 2?

Comment: No, the right bracket does not do anything, I just "accidentally" wrote them on my note =)) Sorry if that confused you

Comment: @LêNguyênBách OK, thanks, I updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you so much =D